# How can i print the memory address of: mystr: .asciiz "mips" in mips?

Tags: assembly, mips

How can i print the meomrdu addres of mystr in this code:

```
.data
mystr: .asciiz "mips"

.text
.globl main
main:
addi    $2,$0,4
la      $4,mystr
syscall
```

Comment: By using system call 1 instead of system call 4. Note that this will print the address in base 10. If you want base 16 you can either use system call 34 in MARS, or write your own number to hex string converter if you're using some other simulator.

Comment: so you mean i must do something like: addi $2 , $0, 1 and then syscal but when i must load addres of mystr? sorry i am copletly begginer

Comment: i did this addi 
$2, $0, 1   
la  $4,mystr 
syscall
and i got 2685000992 is that correct?

Comment: I don't know. You'll have to check in the simulator whether that's where `mystr` is located.

Comment: No, that is not correct.  You should have gotten 268500992.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to print it

```
li $v0, 4
la $a0, mystr
syscall
```

a syscall with 4 in register $v0 lets the mips compiler know you are trying to output a string. With that string loaded into the $a0 register, the register used from string output, you are able to print it out.